# Static library use

Tags: ios, xcode, static-linking, objective-c++

I have a static library that has another static library inside of it. 
 Let's call them LibA and LibB.
  LibA is the outward facing library or in other words, LibA calls on LibB internally and LibB has no outward facing function calls. 
 LibA's header is extern C so that the names do not get mangled. 
 I have tested this library using Swift and it works flawlessly.
However when I try to use it inside of a Obj-C project, I get the following errors :

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:


  _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:


  _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o


 "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:


 _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o


"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:


 _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o


 "_UIApplicationMain", referenced from:


 _main in main.o


 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64


 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have made sure that both LibA and LibB are built for the architecture x86_64.  
Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: I was able to solve this issue.  Under the Build Phases, I had to add the UIKit.framework to the Link Binary with Libraries.  This fixed the errors and allowed me to use my Library.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: The symbols it's complaining about are from UIKit.  I'll guess it's related to your actual app rather than your libraries.

Comment: Delete derived data from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and then clean, build again. Hope it works.

Comment: This looks like UIKit is not linked in the project. See that it is linked in the greater project, or remove the dependencies from the linked library. I strongly suggest moving to dynamic frameworks.

Comment: I did try deleting the DerivedData folder and that unfortunately did not fix it.  I did comment out everything that references my library and the errors are still there so it seems that that is the problem.  Any ideas on how to fix these?

Comment: If your library is statically linked and internally accesses `UIResponder` or `UIViewController`, the linker will fail. Add `UIKit.framework` to your app's target.

Comment: @PatrickDoherty Added as answer. Please accept if this has helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `UIKit.framework` to your app's target.